# How exactly does the King Cold family line work with transformations?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

The first member of the Frieza Clan that we see is Chilled, whom fights the Super Saiyan Bardock. He appears to be in his descendant Frieza's First Form, though he never transforms to in the fight. It is generally assumed that he couldn't...

Then comes King Cold, who appears like his son's Second Form, though he never transforms either. Many think that Frieza's First Form and Chilled are what the race naturally looks like, with King Cold, Frieza, Cooler, and Kuriza being mutants.

All of King Cold's descendants can transform, with Frieza showing it the most. Cooler states that he can, but he doesn't due to him being able to control his Final Form better than Frieza. And Kuriza is shown in both First and Final Forms.

How exactly does it work? Are these forms unique to Frieza, Cooler, and Kuriza? Or does King Cold have them as well?

Answer (score 2):

Since both final form of (Frieza and Cooler) where similar. We can make a logical statement that King Cold could also transform into that final form.

He was never given a chance to transform though, since trunks defeated him so fast.

As you said Cooler was already on his final form since he said he could control it. He didnt need to suppress his powers like Frieza.

If Frieza had trained he would probably be always on his final form, since then he would be able to control it.

Even of the new Dragon Ball Movie, we see that Frieza couldnt control his Golden Transformation so well.